# How to get browser to choose proper DPR

Tags: css

I use this for my iphone 6:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 812px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
{styles}
```

But it renders out-of-whack in iphone X

I use this for iphone X:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 812px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3)
{styles}
```

But it renders out-of-whack in iphone 6

when I attach both to the end of my CSS, the browser uses the last one of course.
I need the browser to use the DPR3 for iphone X and DPR2 iphone 6. How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated. (I searched but could find nothing in the archives about this particular problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my sites and working fine in all devices in my experience. Also with iPhone X.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   //HERE YOU WRITE ALL STYLE THINGS
}
```